# Java - processing file in memory without the disk R/W

Tags: java, file, memory, disk

I am receiving files through a socket 
and saving them to database.

So, i'm receiving the byte stream, and passing it 
to a back-end process, say *Process1* 
for the DB save.

I'm looking to do this without saving 
the stream on disk. So, rather than storing the incoming stream 
as a file on disk and then passing that file to *Process1*, 
i'm looking to pass it while it's still in the memory. 
This is to eliminate the time-costly disk read & write.

One way i can do is to pass the byte[] to *Process1*.
I'm wondering whether there's a better way of doing this.

TIA.

Comment: Save in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`? But it will eat heap space, of course

Comment: @fge will look into it -- seems to be what im looking for. handling the byte[] length n all for me (?)

Comment: It will indeed, yes. Heap hungry but it will

Comment: write it as an ans & i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). It is, essentially, a growable `byte[]` which you can write into at will, that is in the limit of your available heap space.

After having written to it/flushed it/closed it (although those two last operations are essentially a no-op, that's no reason for ditching sane practices), you can obtain the underlying byte array using this class's [`.toByteArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray--).

Answer (score 0):

[Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: He already has a Socket: "I am receiving files through a **socket** [...]"